# Increase root volume for ubuntu 18.0.4

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ssd

I have just installed Ubuntu as my base OS. While installing, it asked me whether I want to erase everything or install along with windows. I choose erase everything.

Everything got installed pretty well. **But, my laptop has a SSD along HDD**. I don't know why,but just **found out that Ubuntu's root directory is using just SSD and not at all HDD.**
**(/dev/nvmeon1)**
[image]

**I am getting error low disk space every now and then**. I have mounted the volumes of HDD yet, the root isn't able to use them.**(/dev/sda)**

[image]

I have 1TB of drive but not sure why Ubuntu didn't used it. **Can I somehow use these volumes in root?**(Though as I see those in the root partition table i.e. /dev/nvmeon1)I don't want to re-install it to resolve this. It would be great if someone can share their thoughts.

Comment: Erase everything & install implies the selected disk, including multiple disks only if only if they are an array (raid etc); at least in my experience. I usually opt for using *Manual Partitioning* (or *something-else* depending on installer used) so I can setup what I need and not be limited to installer options. You can migrate directories from your ssd to your hdd (once it's formatted) though I usually do this using a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media), then reflect changes in *file-system table* (/etc/fstab) then boot to test.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Would you please elaborate on what changes are you suggesting to be made once I boot by a 'live' system?

Comment: I would move /home/ to hdd, /opt/,  /usr/ possibly too. Personally I'd not move them all in one hit, I'd move directory one at a time, see the space available, use it (ie. test) and if you decide more space move the next directory.  You may notice a performance hit with all of /usr/, so you could move only some of it's subdirectories (thus keeping /usr/ on the ssd) but your actual usage (ie. your least used programs are what you want on hdd) will dictate.  libs would likely have too big a performance hit so I'd try and keep on ssd. Use `du` to look at your sizes of directories/subdirs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. By move, do you mean that I can just copy the directories to HDD?

Comment: Copy `/home` using `rsync` (preferably twice, to make sure you have an exact copy), then replace the original `/home` by a symbolic link using `sudo ln -s /myHDD/home /home`. From that moment on, all access to `/home` will be to your HDD. Replace `/myHDD` with the mount point of your HDD.

Comment: Hi @Jos, I really appreciate your inputs. This sounds way more easy and safe. I am new bee to ubuntu/linux. It would be great if you can share a `sample to copy directories between volumes`. I am trying to look at rsync options but haven't got anything yet.

Comment: (yes by move you could `mv`, myself I'd `cp -pr` (*copy preserve..*) then `diff` to ensure copy was exact; but that's just me... I'd also backup (`rsync` for that one) to another drive off-machine before I `rm`)

Answer (score 1):

Building on @guiverc's suggestion to move one or more large directories to your HDD, starting with `/home`:

- `cp` or `rsync` the current contents. I would use `sudo rsync -alz --progress /home /myHDD/` but whether you use `cp` or `rsync` is mainly a matter of taste. This will create a new directory `/myHDD/home`. Owners and permissions of the files under `/home` should be preserved as well (because of the `-a` flag).
- To be absolutely sure, repeat the command. The second time nothing should be actually copied, except perhaps some cache or history files from an active user, but nothing really significant.
- compare `du -s /home` to `du -s /myHDD/home`. The output should be virtually the same.
- When you are satisfied that the files have all been transferred, do `sudo ln -s /myHDD/home /home`. This will basically delete the directory `/home` on your root partition, and refer all traffic to and from the `/home` folder to the `myHDD` partition.
- At this point, every access to `/home` will actually be to the HDD and the space on your SDD will be freed up.

Make sure that the `myHDD` partition is mounted correctly at every boot. Otherwise you will not be able to login.

Comment: as an insurance policy I would also create a new user who has ability to issue `sudo` before doing above in case above user cannot login just login as this new user and fix things

Comment: Thanks for the details. I copied `/home` to myHDD. I can see the data there, however, `sudo ln -s /myHDD/home /home` when I executed this, the references of /home is still there in SSD volume. Am I missing something?

Comment: You should see an entry for `home` starting with `l` (for `link`) when you do `ls -l /` and the actual entry should look like `home -> /myHDD/home`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see that home is linked by `ls -l` in root `/`

Comment: Then the `ln -s` command must have failed. Did it give any output?